# Swift Enumerate out of Range

Tags: swift, enums

I'm working on making a tile-based adventure game and I'm trying to generate tile maps. I put together some code that removes inland tiles from the list of possible new tile locations. I have a method that detects if a tile is coastal.

```
for (index, tile) in landTiles.enumerate() {
    let coastal = isCoastal(tile.y, x: tile.x)
    if coastal {
        coastTiles.append(tile)
    } else {
        print(landTiles.count)
        print(index)
        landTiles.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}
```

When I run this code I'm getting an `error: index out of range` message. I believe this is because the indexes are getting confused when I delete an item from landTiles. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are removing elements from an array while you enumerate it.
And this is an anti-pattern.

What should you do instead?

### The Tile class

First of all, the `Tile` class should have a `isCoastal` computed property. Something like this

```
class Tile {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
    var isCoastal: Bool { /* your logic goes here */ }

    init(x:Int, y:Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}
```

### Filtering

Now given an array of `Tile`(s)

```
var landTiles: [Tile] = ...
```

you can extract the ones having `isCoastal true`

```
let coastTiles = landTiles.filter { $0.isCoastal }
```

and overwrite the original array with the ones having `isCoastal false`.

```
landTiles = landTiles.filter { !$0.isCoastal }
```

That's it.

Comment: I'll try it. I currently don't have a tile class, tiles are just x-y pairs. I'll make a class and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't need to extend something (like `SKSpriteNode`) then `Tile` can also be a `struct`. Much faster and you don't need to explicitly define the initializer.

Comment: Yeah thats what I was planning on doing.